# Find which application use Ctrl+Comma

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2013, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

I can't use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> in Visual Studio 2013 and Pycharm in windows 8.1. Is there a way to find which application occupy this shortcut/hotkey?

I tried Windows Hotkey Explorer, doesn't work.
[Here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=1452AAA400732A3D!19858&authkey=!AB7fhDo5TRPuk0s&v=3&ithint=photo,.png) is the list.

Here is the [list of the program](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=1452AAA400732A3D!19859&authkey=!ADFmOcmehh5Ul60&v=3&ithint=photo,.png) I installed:

Any help?

Comment: Open Windows Task Manager (or use similar tool, e.g. Process Hacker) and kill process after process (not system ones, of course) checking in between if shortcut start working again. Start with software that runs on startup, also check graphic driver.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is for Chinese user only. This is because of the Sogou Pinyin (搜狗输入法）occupy this shortcut system wide. And it won't release if you just uninstall it.

Go to here to disable it: Language->Advanced settings->Change language bar hot keys

Uninstall it is not working, you need disable that setting then uninstall it.

Answer (score 6):

Adding to @happlebao's answer:

As of 2019, in Windows 10, you need to go to Settings > Devices > Typing > Advanced keyboard settings > Input language hot keys, or just press Windows key and search for "Advanced keyboard settings" to find the hotkey settings.

Then disable the Ctrl+, hotkey.

Comment: In "Advanced keyboard settings" I had to press "Language bar options", go to the "Advanced Key Settings" tab, press the "Change Key Sequence" button, then changed to be not assigned.